# How to import a py file as a module in my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a folder that looks like this:

```
project
|__doc
   |__ demo.ipynb
|__wrap 
   |__wrappers
      |__ __init__.py
      |__ media
        |__ __init__.py
        |__ util.py
```

I am currently writing scripts in `demo.ipynb` in Jupyter Notebook, where I need to import `util.py` as a module. I will be using the functions in `util.py`to run analysis in `demo.ipynb`.

I wrote:
`from project.wrap.wrappers.media.util import util`

But I got the following returned:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

What is a proper way to import such a py file as a module in my Jupyter Notebook, when that py file is in another folder?

Is there a purpose for those *init*.py files?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in `project` (and `wrap`) to make them a module that is able to be imported from

Comment: Or move `ipynb` files up a folder and import from `wrap.wrappers.media`

Comment: @OneCricketeer if there a way to do this without moving the location of the ipynb file?

Comment: Yes. Make each folder have an `__init__.py` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages, although with the current layout, you would have to write `from ..wrap.wrappers.media import util`